# SQLite: dynamic key-value REPLACE using separate table

Tags: sqlite

Using **SQLite**, I'd like replace a number of placeholders in a string, but instead of statically providing the key-value pairs, the placeholders and replacement values must come from a table. This question is best illustrated by example:

```
SELECT
  REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( text_with_placeholders
  , '$NAME', 'Eren')
  , '$TITLE','Mr')
  , '$LEVEL','4th')
FROM table_with_text
```

In my case though, I have a fairly long list of placeholders, which ideally are dynamic, thus simplifying adding and changing values. So instead of changing the query I'd like to add/update records in a key-value table.

Any smart idea's on how to solve this puzzle? Perhaps for inspiration, my (dead-end) road so far was to use SQLite's nice group_concat() function, this together with a cross join enables you to have the rows with the text and the key-pair values as strings on the same row. But then still you need some sort of loop to go through them, so that won't work.

```
      SELECT
        REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( text_with_placeholders
        , '$NAME', 'Eren')
        , '$TITLE','Mr')
        , '$LEVEL','4th')
        , kv.keys
        , kv.vals
      FROM table_with_text
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(key) keys, GROUP_CONCAT(val) vals FROM key_val_table ) kv
```

*I'm aware that the answer to this question probably is Impossible, and that's okay. Still, I'd like to give this a shot given the many brilliant minds at StackOverflow.*

*I'm also aware that this is best done in the target application, instead of in the database. So no need to point that out.*

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think your idea to 
"instead of changing the query I'd like to add/update records in a key-value table"

But I think you should make this step by step:

- first read your key-value-table
- build a query-command (check the result)
- execute the dynamic query-command

replace-function can be used to set the content form the table to the query-pattern you have!

Here is an example to use replace:

```
UPDATE
    contacts
SET
    phone = REPLACE(phone,'410','+1-410');
```

refer to: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-replace-function/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, basically your proposal is moving the solution out of the database, which is a good approach. However I'm specifically looking to solve this within the database only.